# R - Recoding a categorical variable

Tags: r

I've a categorical variable of more than 30 different categories. I would like to recode this variable into a smaller number of categories.

I tried using the `recode`function in the `car` package but didn't understand how to function for more than one new category. 
Here are some examples of the categories I want to re-categorize using `recode`:

```
recode(disaster_subtype, "c('Coastal flood','Riverine flood', 'Flash flood', 'flood')='Flood'")

"c('Tropical cyclone','Convective storm', 'convective storm','Extra-tropical storm','storm')='Storm'")

"c('Forest fire','Wildfire', 'Heat wave', 'flood')='Fire & Heat waves'")
```

Is there a way to make several new categories using this function and is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a more elegant way to do this, but until you find it, you could try something like this (using case_when from dplyr):

I created a variable "disaster_subtype" based on the categories you mentioned.

```
disaster_subtype <- c("Coastal flood", "Riverine flood", "Flash flood", "flood", "Coastal flood", "Riverine flood", "Flash flood", "Tropical cyclone", "Convective storm", "convective storm", "Extra-tropical storm", "storm", "Tropical cyclone", "Convective storm", "convective storm", "Forest fire", "Wildfire", "Heat wave","flood")
```

Now I can create a new variable based on the string patterns that belong to the desired categories.

```
library(dplyr)
new_variable <- case_when(grepl("storm|cyclone", disaster_subtype) ~ "Storm",
                          grepl("flood", disaster_subtype) ~ "Flood",
                          grepl("fire|Heat", disaster_subtype) ~ "Fire & Heat waves")
```

There are two important points to consider:

1. You have to find enough patterns to cover all possible answers (mind capitalization).
2. These patterns shouldn't overlap to avoid mismatches.

Please ask me, if you have questions concerning this approach. And I would also be interested in different solutions.